# TypeError cyclic object value when trying to change a ko.observable from an jquery trigger inside jquery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, durandal, knockout-2.0, durandal-2.0

I'm trying to change a ko.observable value when clicking on a jquery.DataTables table-row to the id of that row.
I'm instantiating the DataTable in durandal's attached function after I fetched data from the server in the activate cycle. Even without any on-click logic, I can't get it to change the observable value after I instantiated the Datatable.

code below:

```
self.attached = function(view, parent) {
    self.selectedCategory().schedule_id(1337);
    self.dt = $('#reservation_schedule_table').DataTable();
}
```

works fine. But, when I write it like this,

```
self.attached = function(view, parent) {
    self.dt = $('#reservation_schedule_table').DataTable();
    self.selectedCategory().schedule_id(1337);
}
```

I get a cyclic object error.

```
TypeError: cyclic object value
return JSON.stringify(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data), replacer, space);
knockou...7981312 (line 537, col 19)
```

Can somebody tell me why that is and how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. Because the only thing that's being returned from the module is a new Instance of the viewModel itself, the DataTable instance had to be relative to the view-parameter of the attached function. Haven't fully understood why this is, yet. But I'm going to read up on it.
For starters, this is how the code should look like:

```
self.attached = function(view, parent) {
    view.dt = $('#reservation_schedule_table').DataTable();
    self.selectedCategory().schedule_id(1337);
}
```

And wherever the Datatable is used inside one of the lifecycle functions, it has to be as view.dt